# What is the py-algorand-sdk equivalent of "./sandbox goal account list"

Tags: python, algorand

**TLDR;** I am running an Algorand PrivateNet in a sandbox. I would like to know how I can use the Python SDK for Algorand to return the address and balance of the accounts on this network.

**Longer version;**
Until now I have been using `"./sandbox goal account list"` to find the account addresses and account balances in Bash, this returns:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [offline] | I3CMDHG236HVBDMCKEM22DLY5L2OJ3CBRUDHG4PVVFGEZ4QQR3X3KNHRMU | I3CMDHG236HVBDMCKEM22DLY5L2OJ3CBRUDHG4PVVFGEZ4QQR3X3KNHRMU | 8012889074131520 microAlgos |
| [offline] | 3NSWKJTYMW3PSZZDIE6NCHMRTOZ24VY5G3OJNDSTYRVRXMZBZVPCGQHJJI | 3NSWKJTYMW3PSZZDIE6NCHMRTOZ24VY5G3OJNDSTYRVRXMZBZVPCGQHJJI | 1001611000000000 microAlgos |
| [online] | 5KLSI3AHMBBDALXBEO2HEA3PBBCBAYT4PIHCD3B25557WGWUZGRTQETPHQ | 5KLSI3AHMBBDALXBEO2HEA3PBBCBAYT4PIHCD3B25557WGWUZGRTQETPHQ | 100000 microAlgos |

I have tried to utilise the algod and v2client.indexer modules as outlined below but instead of the 3 accounts listed above 4 are being listed by my code (the original 3 +1). The code:

```
    #imports
    from algosdk import algod, v2client
    
    # instatiate AlgodClient
    def connect_to_network():
        algod_address = "http://localhost:4001"
        algod_token = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
        algod_client = algod.AlgodClient(algod_token, algod_address)
        return algod_client 
    
    # instantiate IndexClient
    def indexer():
        indexer_token = ""
        indexer_address = "http://localhost:8980"
        indexer_client = v2client.indexer.IndexerClient(indexer_token, indexer_address)
        return indexer_client
    
    # returns all account details from indexer
    def account_details():
        raw_details = indexer().accounts() # <-- I think the error is here because this returns 4 addresses.
        account_details = []
        for details in raw_details["accounts"]:
            account_details.append({"address":details["address"], "amount": details["amount"]})
        return account_details
    
    # returns the amount in each account
    def account_amounts(account_address):
        return connect_to_network().account_info(account_address)
    
    # returns account address and amount for each account
    for detail in account_details():
        print(account_amounts(detail["address"])["address"])
        print(account_amounts(detail["address"])["amount"])
```

This returns:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| I3CMDHG236HVBDMCKEM22DLY5L2OJ3CBRUDHG4PVVFGEZ4QQR3X3KNHRMU | 8013089091731545 |
| NTMTJYBQHWUXEGVG3XRRX5CH6FCYJ3HKCSIOYW4DLAOF6V2WHSIIFMWMPY | 1001636000000000 |
| 3NSWKJTYMW3PSZZDIE6NCHMRTOZ24VY5G3OJNDSTYRVRXMZBZVPCGQHJJI | 1001636000000000 |
| 5KLSI3AHMBBDALXBEO2HEA3PBBCBAYT4PIHCD3B25557WGWUZGRTQETPHQ | 100000 |

1. How can I replicate `"./sandbox goal account list"` with py-algorand-sdk?
2. (Bonus question) what is this extra mystery "account" that appears when I use the SDK compared to Bash?

Answer (score 4):

The issue above arose because like with `./sandbox goal accounts list`I was trying to return the accounts I had keys for locally in the KMD but my call to the indexer `raw_details = indexer().accounts()` was returning all accounts on the network.

To remedy this, instead of importing and using the `v2client.indexer` module import the [`wallet`](https://py-algorand-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/algosdk/wallet.html) module from the `algosdk` library. These are the necessary imports:

```
from algosdk import algod, kmd, wallet
```

Then set up the connections to algod, kmd, and your wallet:

```
# instatiate AlgodClient
def connect_to_network():
    algod_address = "http://localhost:4001"
    algod_token = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
    algod_client = algod.AlgodClient(algod_token, algod_address)
    return algod_client 

# instantiate KMDClient <--- this is used as a parameter when instantiating the Wallet Class.
def key_management():
    kmd_address = "http://localhost:4002"
    kmd_token = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
    kmd_client = kmd.KMDClient(kmd_token, kmd_address)
    return kmd_client

#get wallet details
def wallet_details():
    wallet_name = 'unencrypted-default-wallet'
    password = ""
    kmd_client = key_management()
    return wallet.Wallet(wallet_name, password, kmd_client)
```

You can now return the account addresses held locally in the KMD:

```
keys = wallet_details().list_keys()
```

Now that you have the addresses you can query use the algod client to return the amount of (Micro) Algo held at each of these addresses.